# How can I increase the range of a thrown weapon?

Tags: weapons, pathfinder-2e, throwing-things

I found the Ranger feat (level 4) [Far Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=502):

> Your experience in the field has taught you how to focus your aim at a distance, increasing your accuracy. Double your weapons’ range increments.

Most builds cannot afford a class feat spent on this. Is there a Skill, General or Ancestry feat, or any other solution?

---

Assume the weapon is +1, with the Returning rune.

(I know Alchemists have Far Lobber and Uncanny Bombs, but those are only good for bombs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### There is one such Feat... kind of

[Virga May](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2334) (Storm Hag) Changelings can choose [Favorable Winds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2336) at 5th level.

> [1-action]
> You wrap a shell of favorable wind around a weapon you wield. On your next Strike with a ranged weapon before the start of your next turn, you don't take circumstance penalties on the attack roll due to wind. In addition, if that weapon has a range increment of 10 feet or less, increase its range increment by 10 feet for that Strike.

---

There are a few other Class Feats that do this. If it's important to a person to be able to chuck weapons, they might consider spending a Class Feat on it (especially considering they tend to be the Feats most tightly associated with doing better in combat)

- Rogue, 2nd: [Strong Arm](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1783)
- Turpin Rowe Lumberjack archetype, 6th: [Axe Thrower](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1235)

And a couple that allow you to 'chain' attack(s) from the first target hit

- Monk, 14th: [Whirling Blade Stance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1755)
- Fighter, 2nd: [Rebounding Toss](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1723)

And Feats affecting the penalties for throwing outside of their increment

- Rogue, 6th: [Far Throw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1792)
- Ranger, 20th: [Legendary Shot](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=546)

Comment: No sells or magic items currently?

Comment: I couldn't find anything searching Nethys for "thrown", "range increment", or even just "range". I got hopeful when I saw range mentioned in mithral, but that was just that it's effective against a "range of creatures" lol. Maybe in Guns and Gears?

Answer (score 3):

## Hunt Prey, Kinda

I'm sure if you're already playing a ranger you've seen this, but in case you just missed it while theory crafting a build, [Hunt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=10) allows you to ignore the penalty for the second range increment, effectively already doubling your range:

> You also ignore the penalty for making ranged attacks within your second range increment against the prey you’re hunting.

That means most throwing weapons should be able to throw from 40ft or so without penalty, with some being even higher (e.g. Javelin, Bladed Diabolo, Rungu).